# Wix bootstrapper run msipackage in silent mode

Tags: wix

I've created simple bootstrapper project which installs **MSXML.msi** and **x.msi**. What I want to is execute **msxml.msi** in silent mode and then **x.msi**. but I have absolutely no idea how to pass command line arguments to MSI package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

<Bundle>
    ...
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="MSXML" SourceFile="msxml_XP_x86.msi" />    
      <MsiPackage Id="MSI" SourceFile="x.msi"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `DisplayInternalUI` is what you are looking for. Values for DisplayInternalUI are either 'yes' or 'no'

```
<MsiPackage DisplayInternalUI="no" />
```

Comment: I tried it for several times but with no success, but now it works fine. It's weird, but thanks :)

Comment: Didn't you try to use True/False instead of Yes/No values? :)